# How to turn off cursor focus in SCEditor on MyBB forum?

Tags: autofocus, mybb, sceditor

I've been trying off an on to sort this problem out since February but I just cannot seem to figure it out.

[MyBB](https://mybb.com/) uses the [SCEditor](https://www.sceditor.com/). I'm not personally a huge fan of it but free software is free software. Anyways there is this annoying thing where the editor autofocuses on page load. So no matter where you are on the page, whether it has multiple editors on the page or just one, it jumps to the very last one. Which jumps over a lot of other areas that have inputs as well.

I cannot get the editor to stop focus on page load.

I'd just really like to solve this but have no idea how. Any help is greatly appreciated. The autofocus jumping to the last editor box on the page is getting very annoying.

So far I have tried:

1. attempted in `codebuttons` template under `MyBBEditor = $("#{$bind}").sceditor("instance");` to add `sceditor("instance").focus(false)`.
2. attempted in `codebuttons` template under `autoUpdate: true,` to add `autofocus: false,`.
3. attempted in `codebuttons` template under `MyBBEditor = $("#{$bind}").sceditor("instance");` to add `MyBBEditor.autofocus(false);` and even added `MyBBEditor.autofocusEnd(false);` and still nothing.

My support thread on MyBB has gone stale, even after a few bumps no help.

SCEditor support is by contacting a user via email which I also tried. No response.